# SKStoreReviewController.requestReview freezes simulator

Tags: ios, simulator, skstorereviewcontroller

Every time I call SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() the entire simulator freezes and becomes unresponsive. I always call it from the main thread but has the same problem each time. I am on iOS 12.1.4 using the iPhone XS simulator.

Answer (score 1):

After much frustration it turns out it was only that instance of the simulator that had bugged out for some reason.

Trying it on a device and any other simulator worked with no issues. A swift (excuse the pun) hardware restart of the simulator fixed the issue for me.